# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios, backend

I am trying to get data from an API.

I did this:

```
const testScreen=()=>{

const c =  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/unverifiedProperty/warehouse",{
    headers:{
        'Authorization':'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InN1dGhhcmhpbWFzbmh1OThAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgzODY0NjgwfQ.fxclNhIaNkTnINwOinqFRitX_AA7nQCrLtaFBLY99Tc'
    }
})
console.log(c)

return(
    <View>
        <Text>This is test Screen</Text>

    </View>
)}
```

I want to get data using get requests.

In the terminal, I get this:

```
  Running application on Himanshu.
  Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
  }

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:78:22 in handleError
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I have made sure using postman that I am not having a network issue. You can check in this screenshot:
[image]

Please help me here.

Comment: In which os did you check ? Android or iOS ?

Comment: I use iPhone8 via expo.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the function test screeen closing bracket (}) is missing

secondly axios.get(or any other method) returns a promise .
to access your c you need to do something like.
if the promise fails it will be cached in .catch method you can log it and see if there was some issue

```
const c =  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/unverifiedProperty/warehouse",{
    headers:{
        'Authorization':'Bearer 0000000'
    }
}).then(res=>res)
.catch(err=>err)
```

here is the link for how promises work  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Using this, atleast warming are gone but promise response is empty. If I change "localhost" to ip address, things don't work at all in postman.

Comment: can you plese tell the ios version?

Comment: I am on iOS 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is sample axios.get for getting data from the server

```
const c = axios
  .get("http://localhost:3000/unverifiedProperty/warehouse", {
    headers: {
       Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InN1dGhhcmhpbWFzbmh1OThAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgzODY0NjgwfQ.fxclNhIaNkTnINwOinqFRitX_AA7nQCrLtaFBLY99Tc"
    }
  })
  .then(res => res) //Response from the server
  .catch(err => err);
```

I think your issue is with the name **localhost** if you are testing on Android emulator

Instead of **localhost** try this IP address **10.0.2.2**

Like this :

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000/unverifiedProperty/warehouse
```

Comment: I am not testing on Android emulator. Instead I using iPhone8 via expo. 
Also, your answer solves the warning mssgs but promise response is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if we use Localhost, errors usually occur as you experience, try using your computer's IP Address.

If you are a Linux or Mac user you can check by **ifconfig**

If you are a windows user you can use the command: **ipconfig** in cmd

**Then replace localhost with your IP address.**